# Why is the interface parameter needed for creating a Java Dynamic Proxy

Tags: java, proxy

The method to create a new dynamic proxy instance using Java Proxy has a signature as follows.

```
public static Object newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class<?>[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h)throws IllegalArgumentException
```

I wonder why is the second parameter interfaces needed?
As in the following example, this is how tutorials often show the usage pattern:

```
Hello hello = new Hello();
IHello proxy = (IHello) Proxy.newProxyInstance(IHello.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class[] {IHello.class},
            new HelloHandler(hello));
proxy.hello();
```

From my understanding, we use the classloader to show what kind of object should the proxy object should be interpreted as. Therefore, it would belong to the class of which we supplied the classloader parameter. In this case, it should have exactly the same methods as defined in that class, so why must we still supply it with the second parameter interfaces?

Edited:
My actual curiosity lies in that when would we use different classes for classloader and interface? (A.class.getClassLoader() and new Class[] {B.class}) From the comments and also experimental code I know that it is possible. However the effects does not seem to have any changes (or make program fail). So would there be any situation that different classes should be used? (not just could).

Comment: "it should have exactly the same methods as defined in that class" Which class? A class loader is not a class.

Comment: @Sweeper I thought that the class loader is bounded to that class. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bounded". `getClassLoader` returns the class loader that loaded the class. In any case, You don't technically "need" to pass an interface. You can pass an empty array too. But then the cast to `IHello` would fail, and such an object will not be very useful.

Comment: @Sweeper I see. I think I might change my question a bit, I'm wondering if there is any case that we pass A.class.getClassLoader to the first parameter while passing new Class[] {B.class} as the second parameter?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to ask that instead. But sure you can use different `Class`es. The `Class`es you use for first and second parameters aren't that related. As I said, the first parameter is a `ClassLoader`. It doesn't matter from which class you got the `ClassLoader` from, or whether you got the `ClassLoader` from a `Class` at all.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you very much. I had edited my question.

Comment: @user85421 Thanks! I think I now get that the class loader does not know about the class it comes from.

Comment: The class loader loads thousands of classes.it can’t be used to identify one of them.

Comment: You seem to think that one class loader loads one class, and that is not how it works. In the simplest case, the class loader loads **all** classes in your application. In any case, the class loader for the proxy doesn't need to be the loader that loaded the original class or interface, it just needs to be the one that is used to define the proxy.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Although the class loader can be different from the one that loaded the interface, the interfaces should still be *visible* through the specified class loader though.

Comment: @Sweeper True, I forgot to add that condition (though it is also described in the javadoc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to think that the first parameter is what specifies the interfaces that the proxy object implements. This is not true - specifying the interfaces that the proxy should implement is the job of the second parameter. You can give multiple interfaces, as a `Class[]`, to say that the proxy should implement.

The first argument specifies what class loader should be used to define the proxy object's class.

See [What is a Java ClassLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2424604/5133585) if you don't understand what a class loader is.

In your example, `IHello.class.getClassLoader()` is passed as the first parameter. The fact that `IHello.class` appears in this expression has nothing to do with what interfaces we want the proxy to implement. `IHello.class.getClassLoader()` just gets the class loader that loaded `IHello`. I could also pass `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`, or my own implementation of `ClassLoader` as the first parameter.

All that matters is that the first parameter is a class loader, and it satisfies some requirements, listed in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,java.lang.Class%5B%5D,java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)). The most relevant ones for this question would be:

> - All of the interface types must be visible by name through the specified class loader.
> - All of the types referenced by all public method signatures of the specified interfaces and those inherited by their superinterfaces must
>   be visible by name through the specified class loader.

`newProxyInstance` would throw an exception if any of the requirements are not met.

You often see people doing `SomeInterface.class.getClassLoader()`, and then also passing `SomeInterface.class` as the second parameter, because `SomeInterface` is trivially "visible by name" through the class loader that loaded `SomeInterface`, so it definitely satisfies the requirements.

As an additional example, here is a call to `newProxyInstance` that would throw an exception:

```
Proxy.newProxyInstance(String.class.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[] { I.class },
        (a, b, c) -> {
            System.out.println("Foo");
            return true;
        });

// ...

interface I {}
```

Here, `String.class` is loaded by the platform class loader (because it is a JDK class), but `I` is loaded by the system class loader, as it is an interface I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had misunderstood the relationship between a classloader and a class. Thanks very much for all and especially ***Mark Rotteveel*** for his answer solved my question very clearly. I quote his answer below to close this question:

> In the simplest case, the class loader loads all classes in your application. In any case, the class loader for the proxy doesn't need to be the loader that loaded the original class or interface, it just needs to be the one that is used to define the proxy.