# Learning and Understanding the Xcode Build System

Tags: xcode, build, automation, target

Alright, I'm curious about the build process with Xcode. Setting up multiple Targets, how to automate versioning and generally understanding the system so I can manipulate it to do what I want.

Does anyone have any books or can point me to some documentation somewhere so that I can figure all of this out?

Thanks a ton.

Another thing, if anyone actually sees this since changing it.

But any books anyone is aware of that will focus on Xcode 4? There's Xcode 3 Unleashed but I'd be real curious if there are any books that focus heavily on Xcode 4.

Answer (score 10):

One thing that is really essential for consistent, reproducible, automatable builds is knowledge of the `xcodebuild` command.  Sadly I can't find any official docs on it apart from the manpage (type `man xcodebuild`).  There's a useful guide to automating iphone builds [here](http://nachbaur.com/blog/how-to-automate-your-iphone-app-builds-with-hudson) that includes building with `xcodebuild` and versioning with `agvtool`.  This is just as relevant to general building of Mac apps.

Generally building with xcodebuild is very simple:

```
cd project_dir
xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -configuration Release ARCHS="x86_64 i386" build
```

Once you can build from a script like this it's very easy to slot into an automated build system.

Comment: Now this is the type of stuff I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It works great! But can I get progress of build ? Which one file compiling, how many files in project, etc? thanks

Comment: xcodebuild usually needs some other software like security (open up the user's keychain) and PlistBuddy (update values like build number) to create a fully automated build.

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode build process**

[[LLVM]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66844588/4770877), [Clang LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html), [Swift LLVM](https://apple-swift.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SIL.html)

Xcode uses [`xcodebuild`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/osx-10.13.1.php) internally[<sup>[Example]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027210/4770877)

[image]

**Objective-C language**

```
1. Preprocessing
[Driver][Preprocessing][Parsing and Semantic Analysis] Parser `.m -> AST`
    2.Compiling by compiler(Clang)
    [Code Generation and Optimization](GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL) LLVM IR Generation `AST -> LLVM IR`. 
    3. Assembling
    [LLVM backend] LLVM `LLVM IR -> .o`
4. Static Linking(ld)
5. Output binary
```

Xcode and Objective-C exposes some of these steps:

1. `Preprocessing`:

- Replace macros
- Splits `.h` and `.m`.

  In Xcode, you can look at the preprocessor output of `.m` file by selecting

  ```
    select .m file -> Product -> Perform Action -> Preprocess
  ```

2. `Compiling` - translates a low-level intermediate code.
   Often you can see this file when debug a code that you are not owned. Xcode allows you to review the output.

   ```
    select .m file -> Product -> Perform Action -> Assemble
   ```
3. `Assembling`(produce `.o`) - translates code into object file (`.o` file)[<sup>[Mach-O]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214522/4770877) In Xcode, you’ll find these object files inside the `<product_name>.build/Objects-normal` folder inside the derived data directory.
4. `Static Linking`(produce `.app`, `.a`, `.framework` ...)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61140381/4770877) - It is a part of static linker that has to resolve symbols between object files and libraries/frameworks. This process produce a merged executable file which can contain additional resources and dynamic binary
5. Output binary

**Swift language**

```
LVVM Frontend

1. Preprocessing
[Parse module] Parser `.m -> AST`
[Sema module] Type checking > type-checks AST and annotates it with type information
    2.Compiling by compiler(Swiftc)
    [SILGen module] SIL Generator `AST -> raw SIL` > optimizations
        `Guaranteed Optimization Passes`, `Diagnostic Passes` `raw SIL -> canonical SIL. This optimization is applied in any case 
        `Optimization Passes`(SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL) 
    [IRGen] LLVM IR Generation

LVVM Backend
    3. Assembling
    [LLVM backend] LLVM `LLVM IR -> .o`
4. Static Linking(ld)
5. Output binary
```

**Swift Example**

```
import Foundation

class ClassA {
    func foo(param: String) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

**AST**

```
-dump-parse            Parse input file(s) and dump AST(s)
-dump-ast              Parse and type-check input file(s) and dump AST(s)
-print-ast             Parse and type-check input file(s) and pretty print AST(s)
```

```
# xcrun swiftc -dump-parse "ClassA.swift" 

(source_file "ClassA.swift"
  (import_decl range=[ClassA.swift:8:1 - line:8:8] 'Foundation')
  (class_decl range=[ClassA.swift:10:1 - line:14:1] "ClassA"
    (func_decl range=[ClassA.swift:11:5 - line:13:5] "foo(param:)"
      (parameter "self")
      (parameter_list range=[ClassA.swift:11:13 - line:11:27]

...
```

```
#xcrun swiftc -dump-ast "ClassA.swift" 

(source_file "ClassA.swift"
  (import_decl range=[ClassA.swift:8:1 - line:8:8] 'Foundation')
  (class_decl range=[ClassA.swift:10:1 - line:14:1] "ClassA" interface type='ClassA.Type' access=internal non-resilient
    (func_decl range=[ClassA.swift:11:5 - line:13:5] "foo(param:)" interface type='(ClassA) -> (String) -> Int' access=internal
      (parameter "self")

...
```

```
# xcrun swiftc -print-ast "ClassA.swift"
import Foundation

internal class ClassA {
  internal func foo(param: String) -> Int
  @objc deinit
  internal init()
}
```

```
#xcrun swiftc -frontend -emit-syntax "ClassA.swift" | python -m json.tool

{
    "kind": "SourceFile",
    "layout": [
        {
            "kind": "CodeBlockItemList",
            "layout": [
                {
                    "kind": "CodeBlockItem",
                    "layout": [
                        {
                            "kind": "ImportDecl",
                            "layout": [
                                {
                                   
...
```

**SIL**

```
-emit-silgen           Emit raw SIL file(s)
-emit-sil              Emit canonical SIL file(s)
```

```
# xcrun swiftc -emit-silgen  "ClassA.swift"                      

sil_stage raw

import Builtin
import Swift
import SwiftShims

import Foundation

class ClassA {
  func foo(param: String) -> Int
  @objc deinit
  init()
}

// ClassA.foo(param:)
sil hidden [ossa] @$s6ClassAAAC3foo5paramSiSS_tF : $@convention(method) (@guaranteed String, @guaranteed ClassA) -> Int {
// %0 "param"                                     // user: %2


sil_vtable ClassA {
  #ClassA.foo: (ClassA) -> (String) -> Int : @$s6ClassAAAC3foo5paramSiSS_tF // ClassA.foo(param:)
  #ClassA.init!allocator: (ClassA.Type) -> () -> ClassA : @$s6ClassAAACABycfC // ClassA.__allocating_init()
  #ClassA.deinit!deallocator: @$s6ClassAAACfD // ClassA.__deallocating_deinit
}



// Mappings from '#fileID' to '#filePath':
//   'ClassA/ClassA.swift' => 'ClassA.swift'

...
```

**LLVM IR**

```
-emit-ir               Emit LLVM IR file(s)
```

```
xcrun swiftc -emit-ir  "ClassA.swift"
; ModuleID = '<swift-imported-modules>'
source_filename = "<swift-imported-modules>"
target datalayout = "e-m:o-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx12.0.0"

%objc_class = type { %objc_class*, %objc_class*, %swift.opaque*, %swift.opaque*, %swift.opaque* }

define i32 @main(i32 %0, i8** %1) #0 {
entry:
  %2 = bitcast i8** %1 to i8*
  ret i32 0
}

...
```

```
-emit-object           Emit object file(s) (-c)
-emit-executable       Emit a linked executable
```

[[Build With Timing Summary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843319/4770877)

Also you can use Xcode `Report Navigator` to learn more about build process. Moreover `Xcode v14` includes a great feature to visualisation and analyzation of build process

```
Show the Report navigator -> <select build> -> <right_click> -> Show in Timeline

//or

Show the Report navigator -> <select build> -> Editor -> Open Timeline
```

[image]