# xcode 7.3 crashes while archiving react native app

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native, ipa

I didn't catch since when, but now my xcode crashes if i try to archive my react native ios app.

already did:

- project clean & re-download
- tried previous success git versions of my app (same: crashes while archiving)
- uninstall and install fresh xcode 7.3
- disable/enable source control in preferences

so i'm out of ideas now and totally stuck, any help welcome

Comment: Did you try going to Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details, click Download All and click Done, after that make sure in the build settings you picked right provisioning profile, try to restart xcode and archieve and see. It fixed my problem with archiving.

Comment: @shailu0827 yep, it didn't help

Comment: Can you try doing this, pod update and in the build settings "Enable Clang Module Debugging" to NO

Comment: What error Xcode shows after crashing in the report/reopen popup ?

Comment: Remove Xcode from the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490048/learning-and-understanding-the-xcode-build-system report back if you get any errors from the log xcodebuild produces.

Comment: sry guys, i was in hospital, gonna try today!

Comment: What's the specific crash you're getting?

Comment: @amb I couldn't get any output or logs, I reinstalled everything except OS, but still getting this crash, and of course tried everything from this and others threads and still no results

Comment: Have you tried to run Xcode 7.3.1?

Comment: @amb yep, updates&reinstallations didn't help me :(

Comment: still crashing... dear apple wtf :c