# Are Swift structs ALWAYS stored in the stack?

Tags: swift, memory, struct, heap-memory, stack-memory

During an interview I was asked to outline the differences between *structs* and *classes* in Swift. Among my points, I made the argument that *structs* are stored in the stack (space for them is reserved at compile-time) whereas *classes* are stored in the heap (space is allocated at run-time).

The interviewer then said he would really test how deep my knowledge of Swift is and then asked me if *structs* are **always** stored in the stack. After some back and forth, he made this statement:

> If a struct is more than 3 words long, then it is allocated in the heap

I have done some research online and I cannot seem to find this anywhere. Can anyone confirm or reject the validity of this statement? Also, feel free to add any relevant/valid information.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441456/swift-stack-heap-understanding) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift stack/heap understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441456/swift-stack-heap-understanding)

Comment: If I remember correctly, an *existential container* (a value of a protocol type) has a three word buffer for its value, and larger values are stored on the heap.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/?time=1631

Comment: thank you @MartinR, I appreciate your help. I will probably delete this question since there are so many votes to close it. Nevertheless I very much appreciate it!