# How to see details of exceptions in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I set it up so that it has a breakpoint for all exceptions, but I'm getting nothing useful.

Here is what I see on the left:

[image: useless]

It just points to the code causing the error without any explanation of why the code is causing an error.
Here is the code it points to:

[image]

And here is what it shows in the debug area below:

[image]

The console shows no errors either.

Where do I see what exceptions are being thrown? When I was using Eclipse on Windows for Android development it always gave me details.

Comment: The console window should have the error information, have you check that?

Comment: Yes, it has nothing. It just has the prints I made and then nothing.

Comment: Then hit continue again and it should crash and print the error

Comment: No, I hit continue multiple times and it doesn't give any errors in the console.

Comment: Then you should probably take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238673/xcode-exception-breakpoint-doesnt-print-details-of-the-exception-being-thrown