# How to fix "Clang Error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" in Swift?

Tags: admob, swift2, xcode7

I put GoogleMobileAds.framework in my apps and when I try to Archive it (validate and submit to the App Store) it's not working, It finds some errors.

When I started these apps my mac's name was **retina** but then I restored my mac and now it's name is **blacksn0w** .
How to fix them?

> App 1:
>   [image]
>
> App 2:
>   [image]

Comment: See: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/55075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens because your GoogleAdmob SDK was built with `Enable Bitcode = no`, but your project target is built with `Enable Bitcode = yes`.

So just change it to NO in your target's buid settings.

[how to ENABLE_BITCODE in xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

Comment: I am also getting same error `linker command failed` but its doesn't solves by disabling the bitcode.