# ENABLE_BITCODE issue. Xcode 7 archiving issue

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, crashlytics, fabric.io

```
ld: '....../Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSInternalReport.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocati
```

on)

do I need to update version of Fabric? or just enable [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)?

Comment: Had the same issue, it shouldn't be a problem with Fabric, just follow the instructions to enable bitcode.

Comment: you can search "Bit Code" in the Build Setting Tab, you find "ENABLE_BITCODE = Yes" Then Set  "ENABLE_BITCODE = NO" May Be it's help you

Answer (score 2):

Follow Step :

-> select your project,

->select the **Build Settings** tab,

-> then Search  **Bitcode**

-> then look for "**Enable Bitcode**" =`Yes` option and set it `NO`

Clean And Make Archive May Be it's Work For you.

Answer (score 0):

select your project, select the "Build Settings" tab, then look for "Enable Bitcode" option and set it to "No"

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here.

Fabric and Crashlytics both support Bitcode enabled apps. You need to be on version 1.5.1 of Fabric and 3.3.1 of Crashlytics. You can also disable Bitcode as mentioned in other answers.

Release notes are here for [reference.](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/changelog.html#crashlytics)

Comment: i have 2.0.3 version as I've checked on Fabric app

Comment: i have 2.0.3 version of app as I've checked on Fabric app. and I have 3.3.4 crashlitics

Comment: 2.0.3 would is the version of Fabric.app, but Fabric.framework should have a different version number. What value do you see on Fabric.framework?

Comment: oh, ok I've got it ) I will try that you recommended.