# Error with Google Play Game Service on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am getting this error:

> ERROR: GPGSAppController.mm GIDSignIn.h File not found error

I am using [Google Play Game Service plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) for leaderboard and Achievements, and every thing is working fine in android but when I build to IOS and try to run my project to an iOS device I keep getting this error and I couldn't find a solution to it for hours now.

I tried to deleted everything related to Google Play service (After creating a back up of course) and the app installed and worked ok, except it was a bit laggy but that is a another issue. So I'm sure the problem comes from Google Play Service, but I have no clue how to fix it. Again I'm new to Xcode and iOS development in general and even Mac.

I also get this message after building the project in Unity:

> TO FINISH CONFIGURING THE EXPORTED XCODE PROJECT
>
> 1. Add these frameworks:
>
>    AddressBook.framework
>        AssetsLibrary.framework
>        CoreData.framework
>        CoreTelephony.framework
>        CoreText.framework
>        Security.framework
>        libc++.dylib
>        libz.dylib
> 2. Add the following bundles and frameworks from the Google Plus
>      and the Google Play Games C++ SDKs. These can be downloaded from
>      https://developers.google.com/games/services.
>
>    GoogleOpenSource.framework
>        GoogleSignId.bundle
>        GoogleSignId.framework
>        gpg.bundle
>        gpg.framework
>
>    Note: Make sure the bundles are copied to application.  This can be
>      verified under Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources.
> 3. Add the '-ObjC' linker flag. To do this, select the top-level project
>      object, select the 'Unity-iPhone' build target, then go to the
>      Build Settings tab. Search for Other Linker Flags and add
>      the '-ObjC' flag to that list.
>
> ** Note: To run in the simulator, use Unity 4.6.8 or greater.

[ios_instructions on plugin repository](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/ios_instructions)

But I have no idea how to do any thing above as am not familiar with iOS development. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try applying instructions from this message? Furthermore, implementing Google Play services on iOS is just a bad idea in my opinion.

Comment: @RafalWiliński I'd like to know why this would be a bad idea. When using Unity with https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity I suppose you get additional informations on Google Developer dashboard for your game if it's linked and available for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im going through that aswell, and for #1 it has to be done in xcode, here's a screenshot of how to add those [libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuRct.png)

And [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFHw2.png) is for #3

Hope that helps :) and I'll get back to you about #2 when I've found out about it ;)

Answer (score 2):

@aimozs answer was right for indicating where to add required files, a few google search gave me the answers;

### From instructions (didn't work for me, scroll down)

> AddressBook.framework
>   AssetsLibrary.framework
>   CoreData.framework
>   CoreTelephony.framework
>   CoreText.framework
>   Security.framework
>   libc++.dylib
>   libz.dylib

These can all be located directly when linking frameworks. (In my case, `libc++.dylib` and `libz.dylib` were already linked, and I couldn't find them somehow, but regenerating your xcode project should add these two again.

> GoogleOpenSource.framework

I've found it here:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_1_creating_the_console_name_project

> GoogleSignId.bundle
>   GoogleSignId.framework

Found them in:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/
(I grabbed latest version `Google Sign-In SDK 3.0.0`)

> gpg.bundle
>   gpg.framework

I found them here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks
(Grabbed `Play Games C++ SDK Version 2.1`)

Also, the following part of the message seemed important:

> Make sure the bundles are copied to application

I tried to copy bundle files to root of the project, but I still get the same error.

### Solution: CocoaPods and the `podfile`!

*I saw the `PodFile` in xcode project directory!*.
Here you go; make sure you followed these steps:
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#ios-setup

Then see https://cocoapods.org/

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
pod install
open Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace
```

Way better than manually copying files everywhere! ;)

**Note**: I also had to disable `bitecode` because I was having a linker error concerning `GoogleOpenSource`:

> You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

It doesn't seem to be compiled with `bitcode` enabled, solution in here:   [how to ENABLE_BITCODE in xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

Build, enjoy and focus on making awesome games!

### Linked questions

There's also a small discussion here:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/googleplus-googleplus-h-file-not-found-gpgsappcontroller-mm-xcode.294398/

A similar issue on UnityAnswers:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1098655/gpgsappcontrollermm-gidsigninh-file-not-found-erro.html