# Swift 2 IOS 9 = clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

[image: Screenshot of the XCode error log]

Hi, I've a problem regarding Parse. today is my first day using it, started out with 4 errors now it's only one left. I have a hard time understanding objective C with swift, started 3 days ago. While trying to understand this line of error and what makes this error appear? Is it a bug that has to be forced through or is it something that I'm missing?

Yes, I have read all other posts before even considering posting my own question. It seems that a lot of people have this problem, but without getting a real good understanding answer to "Why this ERROR pops up, and how to prevent it".

It seems that I can only post 2 images at maximum and I've linked you one. If you need anything else for deciphering the problem, please, I do not mind if you ask for more. =)

Comment: Seems like you have a problem with ParseUI framework, check build settings if you have non-existent framework added.

Comment: I have them all added, can show you screenshot if you want =)

Comment: This problem causes with me also when I using opencv 2 framework with others like Firebase and until now I couldn't fix it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app 'Package content'/ wether your framework is copied to app or not?
location: yourapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/
If parseUI is not in the frameworks -> go to your target in Xcode-> Add framework to 'Linked Binary With Libraries'

I hope, this will resolve your issue.

Comment: @RobinAlsalehy: Are you still getting the same error or some other error?

Comment: Still getting the same error, I think that the documents just got misplaced somehow. I'm starting a new project and do the same thing as earlier to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove one of the frameworks and another error appeared with a new framework. Apparently, as you said, they are not in the package they should be in. That's what the code says. But when I check the contents of my app, I can find the frameworks that supposedly be in myapp.app/contents/Framework in

=

myapp.app/contents/developer/platforms/IphoneOSplatform/developer/SDKs/IphoneOS.SDK/System/library/frameworks/'here they are'

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but you're not going to like it!

I have read a lot about this problem, it seems there is a bug in Xcode, I think. When trying to add the frameworks, they go to another library, it looks like it's on the right path on Xcode but not in the content inside the app installation. Doesn't matter how much you try to delete and try to install the frameworks yet again, they always end up somewhere else. I'm not good of a programmer so I don't have the perfect solution here, but at least it will save you time.

Save the codes you have written or the files that the codes are written on. Delete the old project, create a new project, install parse before you do anything else and then upload your files back in again.

Comment: Just try below steps:
> Click on your project in the Project Navigator.
> Click your target in the project editor.
> Click on the Build Phases tab.
> Choose Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Copy Files Build Phase.
> Click the disclosure triangle next to the new build phase.
> Choose Frameworks from the Destination list.
> Drag ParseUI.framework from the Project Navigator left sidebar to the list in the new Copy Files phase.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried disabling `Bitcode`?

I did it in my case as suggested in [Enable/disable Bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

as you can see in the pic attached

[image: disabling Bitcode]