# XCode fail to build facebook plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova, telerik

When I try with `cordova build ios` or `cordova run ios`, the build is success and deploy to simulator. However, when I try to run it in XCode to deploy it to device, the build end up with this error:

```
ld: 'MyApp/Plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK(FBLikeButtonBackgroundSelectedPNG.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If I remove the facebook plugin (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Facebook), it will build success. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you enable or disable bitcode as Xcode say: "You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target" ?

Comment: @CyrilleGuimezanes Thanks for your comment. How can I enable or disable bitcode in XCode?

Comment: This post will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7

Comment: @CyrilleGuimezanes Thanks for your link. But how can I access to project build settings page?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/EditingBuildSettings.html