# Xcode - Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Linker command failed with exit code 1 when change xcode version

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

While updating my iOS Developer Course to Xcode 7.2, I’ve found that when opening Xcode 6.4 apps in Xcode 7.2, even when going through the upgrader, I’m left with the error "does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

and i have searched in "internet" and so many peoples saying that

Clearing the "Test Host" values in the Build Settings of my "Tests" target see my below image but "how can i clear them" and how can i fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Please show the rest of the error.  If you look at the build log there will be messages immediately before ‘linker command failed" that say **why** it failed.

Comment: @Plillips Mills please see i have shown rest error also please help me

Comment: You still are not showing the error message that comes **before** "linker command failed".

Comment: see now i have pasted all eroror what i am getting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to ENABLE\_BITCODE in xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search your target's Build Settings for "bitcode".  Change the setting for Enable Bitcode to No.

Or you can do what the error suggests: "obtain an updated library from the vendor".