# ipa size is increased instead of decreasing Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

Previously I was using `Xcode7.0.1` but now I am using `Xcode7.2` , previously size of `ipa file` of my project was around `44mb`. Now I have deleted `22mb of unused images` from my project, Size of overall project is decreased by `22mb` and then i generated `ipa file` its size increased instead of decreasing. Now its size is `53mb`. Any ideas what could be the possible reason for this kind of peculiar behaviour?

I also followed similar discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/519) but nothing get out of it.

For generating ipa file I followed following steps:

```
Xcode -> Product -> Archive
```

Comment: Are you sure you deleted them, or did you remove references to them?

Comment: Try cleaning the project before archiving. Steps: Xcode -> Product -> Clean

Comment: @kpsharp if i only remove reference, project size could not be decreased. I have deleted them from my project file.

Comment: @kpsharp Archive size should decrease even if only the references are removed.

Comment: @ZeMoon your solution not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Bitcode feature of app. It is enabled by default.

For disabling this feature Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

After disabling it, make sure the app is working fine.. also make sure you clean your project before creating ipa file.