# SDK does not contain bitcode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, arm64, bitcode

In one of my project i am integrating paytab ios sdk while integration error occurs that is

> a(PayTabCardReaderViewController.o)' does not contain bitcode.
>   I have try with enable bitcode=No

but after enable bitcode=no it show me more 40 erros,any one know can we disable bitcode for only 1 sdk/library only ?

> Error: a(PayTabCardReaderViewController.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 5):

**Solution** You have to disable bitcode option in the "Build Settings" tab on the workspace / project level. Do not forget CocoaPods if you use it. Manual :  [how to ENABLE_BITCODE in xcode 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31205133/how-to-enable-bitcode-in-xcode-7)

**What's the "Bitcode"?** Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.

[image]

Comment: If the bitcode option was disabled then you will not see the warning "You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled". I think that you have not disabled it for workspace / project level

Comment: i have tried it at project level earler and again try after your comment but finding same issue..

Comment: 1. Do you use Cocoapods ? Did you disabled "Enable Bitcode" for debug and release ?