# How to enable App Thining feature?

Tags: ios, ios9, app-thinning

I'm reading the `App Thinning (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)` section of the Apple's [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW3). It describes `App Thinning` and its components, but I don't find if the developer needs to do something to take advantage of this feature, or if it is automatically handled...

Thanks in advance

Comment: By Bitcode enabled your App thining is enabled

Comment: https://www.appcoda.com/app-thinning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit bitcode to the app store and and you are fine. Apple takes care of it from there. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466484/363777) has details on how enableing bitcode works.

Comment: Pretty sure this is somewhat wrong. Even without bitcode enabled, as long as you're on iOS 9+ you'll get App Slicing (one component of App Thinning) for free.