# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 (Have not changed the project's name)

Tags: swift, cocoapods

In Xcode 7, I'm Getting the following error:

ld: library not found for -lOMGHTTPURLRQ
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Most of the StackOverflow answers for this error say that it is due to a project's name being changed. I have not changed the name of my project. What do I do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Comment: I have the same problem a few days ago because I had a library partially installed. If you are using cocoa pods, make sure you check your project files for anything still included from past pods installed.

Comment: Try [disabling Bitcode.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32466484/5143847) It is a common reason why this error is received.

Comment: @penatheboss I have disabled bitcode and I was able to solve part of the issue thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option. Still getting the one error above.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try:

- Delete DerivedData (This one usually works for me)
- Disable bitcode in your project settings
- Project clean
- Delete podfile.lock, .xcworkspace and pods folder then after, do a "pod install"

Hope one of these will help you ;)

Comment: I have tried all 4 of these now and the error still appears. Are there known errors with the OMGHHTPURLRQ pod?