# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Parse.com and Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

so today I updated my code to Swift 2 and now my app won't run because apparently the Parse Frameworks I was using have expired or something.  This is the message I get: ld:

***'/Users/tripphillips1/Desktop/Spotter/Parse.framework/Parse(PFAnalytics.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64***

Does anyone know what this means and how i can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything about expiry.  Here's a post that explains the "bitcode" concept: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7

Comment: Im still really confused? Does that mean I need to archive my project first? Also I made sure that all of my Parse Frameworks are up to date and they are.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found a solution to my problem.  You have to go into the Build Settings and disable the Bitcode.  Simple as that.  Now it runs fine.