# Xcode requested "bitcode" for FastPdfKit

Tags: ios, xcode, fastpdfkit

XCode7 requested "bitcode" to be enabled for FastPdfKit, this library "FastPdfKit" is not updated from year ago, any idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get away by turning-off bitcode for your main target, possibly also that framework if that has its own target. (Target -> Build Settings -> Enable Bitcode -> off)
 This will disable some features like appthinning probably but you should be able to build project.

Comment: thanks, but i can't disable app thinning feature, i will try another library if there is no other solution.

Comment: just to note without bitcode the app will have the same size as it used to have during iOS 8, app-thinning is not yet live in the appstore at the moment anyway , you can read more about it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7