# Xcode 7.0.1 caused a Linker Command Failed with Exit code 1 error

Tags: ios, linker-errors, xcode7, bitcode

Yesterday I updated MacBook Pro to El Capitan. I had `Xcode 6.1` Since the update Xcode wouldn't open `Xcode 6.1` but I was FORCED to download `Xcode 7.0.1` I didn't want to upgrade but I was forced. I created my app with Objective-C. Submitted it to apple and it's currently "pending developer release".

I want to change something but now out of nowhere with `Xcode 7.0.1` I get an error that I never received with `Xcode 6.1`.

```
 ld: '/Users/markjak/Desktop/Stick Down   copy/Leap Up/LibAdapterIAd- 1.0.0/libAdapterIAd.a(GADMAdapterIAdInterstitial.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
```

How do I do what Xcode 7.0.1 want me to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just disable the bitcode from the Build Settings

[image]

Because your library not support the bitcode.

[Apple documentation reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) for bitcode.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me there. I'll give you best answer, when StackOverflow allows me to.

Comment: But what if I need bitcode enabled? Without bitcode enabled I am unable to get the dSYM file from iTunes Connect after the archive has been uploaded. And Xcode won't let me download the dSYMs file from the window organizer it just says "no dSYM file available for this build...", which leaves me with no way to get the dSYM file and use it to symbolicate crash reports...

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly states that your library (libAdapterIAd) does not support [bitcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30722686/988169)
In xcode7 + , [bitcode is enabled by default](http://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8991). So you just have to disable it by following below steps:-

1. Click on Target build settings.
2. Search for bitocde.
3. Set `No` to Enable bitcode

[image]