# Bitcode bundle could not be generated

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, archive

I followed this tutorial [Create an Uber like Splash Screen](https://www.raywenderlich.com/133224/how-to-create-an-uber-splash-screen) to add a Splashscreen to my app. I copied the SplashScreenUI Framework to my Project under Frameworks. Everything works fine and it runs on the simulator. But when I try to archive my app I get the following error:

*bitcode bundle could not be generated because ... was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)*

Also I am able to run the app on my iPhone, but its an older version of my app. It seems to not upload the newer version of the app on my iPhone.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580528/xcode-7-1-swift-framework-app-builds-but-not-archiving/33581287