# Firebase crash report dump_syms is not permitted in iTunes connect upload

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am integrating the Firebase SDK into my app without using CocoaPods for Analytics and Crash Report. When I upload app to the app store, I get the following error. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

> ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'xxxx.app/dump_syms' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure."

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/46

Answer (score 4):

Just remove dump_syms from your targets in XCode. This solved it for me.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/255

Comment: haha! Got the same issue four months later, searched on google, found this and tried to upvote my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error. I asked to Firebase Support Team and they said that *dump_syms* should not be included in the bundle.

Probably the only way to have report properly symbolicated (if you use Apple's Bitcode) is to upload dSYMS files manually.

You can read more on [this issue I opened here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/255)