# Adding app to App Store

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, app-store

I'm trying to release my second app to App Store, but I have some problem.[image]

How I can resolve this problem? I don't understand what I need to do(
Sorry for my English.

Comment: Go to your project then press the build settings tab in the top area, scroll down to signing and under code signing identity press the drop down menu then press "iPhone Developer"

Comment: thanks for the your answer. But I know how to change profiles) But I don't understanding why it conflicting(
I can't to archive my app(

Comment: Try removing all of your provisioning profiles then re-adding them.

Comment: ok! thanks for the help

Comment: Check out this link, I think it will solve your problem: *If it does, please up vote my comment. Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic

Comment: Thank you so much :)
I'm resolve my problem. I unchecked automatically manage signing and check it again. And now it's working good :)

Comment: Sorry for my English

Comment: No problem. Good luck. If you could up vote my comment that would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get conflicting provisioning settings error when I try to archive to submit an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue recently. If you haven't already, you may have to go into the general settings and **disable** automatic code signing, then go into build settings and set everything to distribution.

If you have a problem with submitting your app to the AppStore, use application loader. It takes a few minutes longer, but it works and that's all that counts.