# Xcode 9 Conflicting provisioning settings

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, nativescript-cli

I have a nativescript angular app that is showing an error whenever I try to run it on a real IOS device. **The app runs fine on an emulator and on android.**

The error log is reproduced below. I have tried to use automatically manage signing option in Xcode a suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an/42147217). However this does not work and I keep getting the same error.
I also tried building an archive in Xcode. When I try to Export the archive xcode just shuts down with an error.

The error log is as follows:

```
Xcode build...
2017-10-22 14:14:29.951 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/73/29kcfd816cd6jbsm48mqkp2r0000gp/T/questNewS_2017-10-22_14-14-29.950.xcdistributionlogs'.
2017-10-22 14:14:34.389 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-13233/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTPlatformFamily.m:192
Details:  Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=1 "Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
Object:   <NSBundle>
Method:   +dvt_platformFamilyForBundleAtPath:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff668d15a50>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-10-22 14:14:34.510 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-13233/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTPlatformFamily.m:192
Details:  Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=1 "Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
Object:   <NSBundle>
Method:   +dvt_platformFamilyForBundleAtPath:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff668d15a50>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-10-22 14:14:34.512 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-13233/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTPlatformFamily.m:192
Details:  Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=1 "Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
Object:   <NSBundle>
Method:   +dvt_platformFamilyForBundleAtPath:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff668d15a50>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-10-22 14:14:34.513 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-13233/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTPlatformFamily.m:192
Details:  Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=1 "Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Reached end of file while looking for: Mach-O slice., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
Object:   <NSBundle>
Method:   +dvt_platformFamilyForBundleAtPath:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff668d15a50>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2017-10-22 14:14:34.863 xcodebuild[69327:634958] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7ff66e134cc0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepErrorDomain Code=0 "Locating signing assets failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Locating signing assets failed., IDEDistributionSigningAssetStepUnderlyingErrors=(
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 \"adb has conflicting provisioning settings.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=adb has conflicting provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=adb is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the \"signingCertificate\" entry from your Export Options property list, or switch to manual signing by setting \"signingStyle\" to \"Manual.}",
    "Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 \"ios-device-lib has conflicting provisioning settings.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ios-device-lib has conflicting provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=ios-device-lib is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the \"signingCertificate\" entry from your Export Options property list, or switch to manual signing by setting \"signingStyle\" to \"Manual.}"
)}
error: exportArchive: adb has conflicting provisioning settings.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 "adb has conflicting provisioning settings." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=adb has conflicting provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=adb is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the "signingCertificate" entry from your Export Options property list, or switch to manual signing by setting "signingStyle" to "Manual.}

error: exportArchive: ios-device-lib has conflicting provisioning settings.

Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=8 "ios-device-lib has conflicting provisioning settings." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ios-device-lib has conflicting provisioning settings., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=ios-device-lib is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Developer has been manually specified. Remove the "signingCertificate" entry from your Export Options property list, or switch to manual signing by setting "signingStyle" to "Manual.}

** EXPORT FAILED **

Unable to apply changes on device: 2f5eb251a28d7102c8c421f1f8477b21f67a1470. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 70
```

Comment: Hi Anurag, did you find a solution? I am having the exact same problem and what ever I tried ... no success so far.

Comment: do u have your account setup in xcode and app provisioning profiles for the same build identifier as in apple developer site?

Comment: @Dlucidone The build identifier is the same. For provisioning profiles I am using the XCode managed profile through automatic signing.

Comment: @Ingmar - No luck so far...

Comment: @Anurag: Thx for your reply. However, when I open my app's .xcodeproj file (from the platforms/ios folder) directly in Xcode (9.0.1), hook up my iPhone to my Mac (per cable) I was able to run the app and thereby deploy it without problems to my iPhone. So, I am really not sure what is going on here ...

Comment: @Ingmar - that is working for me too but not tns run ios!!

Comment: can you delete all provisioning profile from keychain and then add them again

Comment: @Dlucidone - Thanks. I deleted all old profiles from the developer portal and recreated them. I then added them to the keychain. Now I am able to run the project from the command line.