# Xcode On Archive Validate Provisioning Profile Conflict

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

When I archive my project than click validate I get the following errors:

> x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-pkg-config has conflicting provisioning
>   settings. x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0-pkg-config is automatically signed
>   for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone
>   Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing
>   identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in the build
>   settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

---

> sqlite3_native.bundle has conflicting provisioning settings.
>   sqlite3_native.bundle is automatically signed for distribution, but a
>   conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been
>   manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "3rd Party
>   Mac Developer Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to
>   manual signing in the project editor.

---

> unf_ext.bundle has conflicting provisioning settings. unf_ext.bundle
>   is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code
>   signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set
>   the code signing identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer
>   Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing
>   in the project editor.

---

> libxml_ruby.bundle has conflicting provisioning settings.
>   libxml_ruby.bundle is automatically signed for distribution, but a
>   conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been
>   manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "3rd Party
>   Mac Developer Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to
>   manual signing in the project editor.

---

> pkg-config has conflicting provisioning settings. pkg-config is
>   automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
>   signing identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in the
>   build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project
>   editor.

---

> terminal-notifier.app has conflicting provisioning settings.
>   terminal-notifier.app is automatically signed for distribution, but a
>   conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been
>   manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "3rd Party
>   Mac Developer Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to
>   manual signing in the project editor.

---

> nokogiri.bundle has conflicting provisioning settings. nokogiri.bundle
>   is automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code
>   signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set
>   the code signing identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer
>   Application" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing
>   in the project editor.

---

> ruby has conflicting provisioning settings. ruby is automatically
>   signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing identity
>   iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing
>   identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in the build
>   settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.

---

> openssl has conflicting provisioning settings. openssl is
>   automatically signed for distribution, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
>   signing identity value to "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" in the
>   build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project
>   editor.

I tried every available answer on stack overflow related to this issue and none of them worked for me.From restarting my computer till revoking the certificates all of them spit the same error messages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to select manual provisioning than to add the certificates manually.

For some reason it gives you the wrong errors tho the push notification provisioning profile was missing.
Simply go to apple.developers and create a provisioning profile per identifier that will solve the problem.
Cherss