# debug version of react-native IOS app builds successfully. Release version fails.

Tags: ios, react-native, provisioning-profile

I've been able to successfully build the Debug version of this IOS app.  However, I'd like to create an IPA to make sure it works on various iphones.  The first thing I did was go product->scheme->edit scheme. I then switched from Debug to Release.  After cleaning, and attempting to build the release version of the app.  I immediately get an error:  `"MYapp has conflicting provisioning settings.  MYapp is automatically signed, but provisioning profile MYApp Distribution has been manually specified. Set the provisioning profile value to "automatic" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor(in target MYapp).`

The first thing I tried was switching Code Signing Style to manual in build settings.  This resulted in a new error:

```
error: Provisioning profile "MYApp Distribution" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Developer: Name here (XXXXXXXX)". (in target 'MYApp')
```

I went back to the General tab in Targets and clicked on "automatically manage signing".  I tried to rebuild and got the same error the first time I tried to build.

I'm not sure where the conflict is coming from.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an) post indicated that simply clicking the automatic signing would do the trick.

I'm quite new to using Xcode and understanding provisioning profiles.

Comment: You need to show a picture of your code signing settings.  It seems like you are trying to build with a distribution provisioning profile and a development certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can not build a release edition. The process of giving a release version is quite different. It goes from Xcode(local) to App Store(testFlight for testing) and then into App Store(Official Release).

I found this [link](https://medium.com/@the_manifest/how-to-publish-your-app-on-apples-app-store-in-2018-f76f22a5c33a) and can relate to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Your provisioning profile isn't valid.  It doesn't have a valid distribution certificate. You have to go to [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com)  and it to certificates and profiles. Create it there and install it via keychain on your macbook. Othervise you can't build an ipa. More info [here](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-a-provisioning-profile-in-ios-77987a7c54c2)