# Xcode: Archiving app with distribution profile is asking for ios development certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to send an app to the Apple app store and am getting really confused about certificates. This is the error I get when I try to do Product -> Archive:

[image]

Here's my setup:

1. I created a provisioning profile with a distribution certificate attached.
2. Under target -> build settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Identity, I put Apple Distribution everywhere (even Debug, because I thought maybe it would stop looking for a development cert)
3. I do not have a device registered, under Destination I have selected "Any iOS Device (arm64)
4. Under Product -> Scheme, I have selected "Release" everywhere except for "Test"

I'm not sure what else to try! I have been cleaning my build folder each time I change one of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

> Under target -> build settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Identity, I put Apple Distribution everywhere

Don't do that.

Archiving, like building and running, requires a *development* provision. When you export from the archive to the Store, *that's* when a distribution provision will be substituted.

Most people should just set all provisioning to Automatic and the right thing will happen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824727/i-get-conflicting-provisioning-settings-error-when-i-try-to-archive-to-submit-an

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm having trouble creating a development provisioning account since I don't have a real device and have been using the simulator. The development provisioning account seems to require a real device be connected

Comment: OK - was able to get a real device connected to a Development provisioning profile. I still get the same error message

Comment: I think I am using a team under my name, but it says TEAM_ID. Is there somewhere else where I need to set the team?