# xcodebuild with bitcode not working

Tags: ios, llvm, xcodebuild, bitcode

I'm building my FAT framework for *distribution* with bitcode using the following command:

`xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
lipo -create /path/to/iphone/framework /path/to/simulator/framework -output /path/to/universal/framework`

My build flags are like this:

[image]

but when I integrate the framework into a different project with bitcode and archive it using:

```
xcodebuild -workspace /path/to/MyApp/app.xcworkspace -scheme app_scheme archive -archivePath /path/to/MyArchive/MyApp.xcarchive | xcpretty
```

I get the following errors:

```
❌  ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/path/to/my/app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture armv7

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


▸ Linking MyApp

❌  ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/tmp/insert_viewer_build/build_1.46.0.2024_1491206455/Frameworks/InsertFramework.framework/InsertFramework' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38830497/1457385

Comment: not working for me

Comment: @AvnerBarr did you manage to solve this problem? If so please explain how, I have similar problem.