# Framework was built without full bitcode - Framework bitcode already enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

Getting this error on Archiving my app. Framework used is my own. So I cross checked. Bitcode in framework is Enabled. Not sure why am I getting this issue. These are the build settings in my framework :

[image]

I followed [**this link**](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9) but didn't work. Tried to set **-fembed-bitcode** in framework's project (not target, but project, since it is recommended in the link) setting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to set 
**Skip Install** to **YES** 
and **Enable Bitcode** to **Yes** in framework build settings.

[image: Skip Install]

[image: Embed Bitcode]

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov how do you export your framework? Do you use Build->Archive?

Comment: No I did not used archived

Comment: try to export framework using Build->Archive and then export build product to some  folder

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko i try to archive and export my framework via build product to some folder but exported products folder is empty

Answer (score 13):

Bitcode is an abstract encoding of an app that can be used to re-compile it in different ways, given a set of instructions. You can confirm whether your binary is bitcode-compatible by running :

`otool -l (my .o or .a file) | grep __LLVM`.

When you build normally, Xcode adds the build flag `-fembed-bitcode-marker` to any clang invocation.

To Add `-fembed-bitcode`: select project Build Settings -> Other C flags, set Debug to `-fembed-bitcode-marker` and Release to `-fembed-bitcode` this will build your lib with bitcode.

**BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE**

If you set `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode` on your User-defined Setting, even during the build phase, the files will be compiled using the flag `-fembed-bitcode`.

And, if you set `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker`, the files will be compiled using the flag `-fembed-bitcode-marker`, independent of the action phase.

So, if you want to enable the bitcode to every action (build and archive), the better way to do so is using the `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE` setting you can do so either manual or by script.

**Manual**

On Build Settings, click on the + sign at the top to add a user-defined build setting with the name `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE`, and set Debug to `marker`, Release to `bitcode`.

Edit schema as Release Then link the library.a file and get the build path get the library form Release folder

**Script**

xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

Comment: not working... maybe you can comment on my post? Would be really grateful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082111/compiled-framework-provides-bitcode-error-when-archiving

Comment: @JhonnyTawk, I upvoted your answer cause you're basically saying what this answer said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830497/9669133  ... yours is just a bit difficult to read but thanks. It pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 3):

if you do below commands

- Enable Bitcode' set to 'YES' Adding
- Flags' Adding 'BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE' with the value 'bitcode' set
  skip install to yes

they will not work until

- flutter clean
- flutter build ios

so that after  you change  build settings you need to run flutter build

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a unity project, and I want to export it to the ios library to integrate with another project. So I need to archive it -> Xcode show "library was built without full bitcode"

My solution for this case is:

- Target -> Framework need archive -> Build setting -> Enable bitcode = NO

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad6LQ.png)

Hope it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add to your project (no target), and for each project into your project (for example: Pods) one "User-Defined" in Build Settings:

BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE
    Debug = marker
    Release = bitcode

Answer (score 0):

Build Settings -> User-Defined -> Add Setting BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE, then set value: bitcode

Answer (score 0):

- Project settings -> Select Framework Target -> Build settings

  add `-fembed-bitcode` in **Other C Flags**
- click + Button -> Add User-Defined Setting

  Key: **BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE**, value: **bitcode**
- Build Active Architectures Only to Yes in Build settings.

Answer (score -1):

For the next soul that comes by and had everything enabled as described in OP but still failed to archive the app using it here's what worked for me:

1. Set up everything as stated in the OP.
2. Archive the product
3. Export it to your own filesystem
4. Find the exported mySadLittleFramework.xcarchive
5. Right click the file, chose Show Package Content
6. Product -> Library -> Frameworks will contain mySadLittleFramework.framework file
7. Drag/copy that file somewhere.
8. Add that file to your app project as framework.
9. Archive the app.

Comment: No Library folder under Product

Comment: If Skip Install is set to True for Release configuration, there won't be Library/Frameworks under Product