# Will Apple reject app if app submit with Enable_Bitcode = No

Tags: ios, bitcode

My app has a lot of third party libraries and social plugging that are not available in bitcode yet. So I can't compile my app with the allow `Enable_Bitcode = YES`.
So I changed it to `NO`, will Apple approve my app for iOS 7.x-9.x?

[image]

Comment: I think wont reject, because from my experience, all Google libraries does not support it.

Comment: Yes,it won't reject ..

Comment: @vicky, please share your reason of rejection given by the apple...

Comment: Hi ilesh , not get rejection :)  just ask question ,  because i read ----- 
Note: Note: For iOS apps, bitcode is the default.....

   https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html          

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-102/?time=407

Answer (score 5):

No. Not yet for iOS apps.

From the [Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2):

> For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. For watchOS and tvOS apps, bitcode is required. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bitcode

Advantage of turning BITCODE on:

Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the store. *Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.*

Answer (score 3):

Apple will not reject such application, it's just your decision enable bitcode or not.

Comment: But disabling bitcode, my app is not showing itunesconnect. any suggestion in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a new version of your app to the store.

For iOS apps, bitcode is the default, but optional. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode. For watchOS and tvOS apps, bitcode is required.

As per apple document bitcode is default but currently optional so your app will get approval until it is compulsory.

Checkout these links for more information:

[Enable bitcode in ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7)

1)https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Answer (score 1):

I was facing problem while uploading app in app store. it stop while processing.
I did Enable_Bitcode = NO
no rejection from apple

Comment: Im looking to solve a problem about bitcode enabled app on app store as you @vaibby

were you able to fix it , if yes , how?

Answer (score 1):

Apple review process does not reject an App because "Enable_Bitcode  NO"