# Mobile App Size on Apple APP Store with Bitcode Enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect

I am new & try to have my First application on App Store.
I have made this app in **UNITY (5.6)**.
The issue I'm Facing is the size of Archive generated by **Xcode (8.3)**, which I have to upload on App Store and is over 100 MB while the same APP on Play store (.apk file) is only 31 MB. See the details Below :
For **Android** its ~ **31 MB** (Approx).
And for iOS its like : Archive Unity-iphone  FILE NAME and File Structure:

 - Unity-iphone 29-07-17, 10.25 PM.**xcarchive** : **630.50 MB**
After Unpacking IT : 
                   -- BCSymbolMaps  : 
        --- 778F6F4C-6E2D-3192-BAY9-FEBDFA98EF0E.bcsymbolmap : 12.8 MB
       
                                                   --- B3746668-8893-3427-A5AB-9741BE4B62B3.bcsymbolmap : 12.9 MB
                    -- **Unity-iphone.app.dSYM : 138 MB**
                    -- **Unity-iphone : 467 MB**
                   -- info.plist

As I searched internet, All are saying to make .IPA File to have estimate of AppSize on App Store. So I exported .IPA File (3 Variants)

- Unity-iphone.ipa (With Bitcode And dSYM Enable) : **163 MB**
- Unity-iphone.ipa ((With Bitcode Disable And dSYM Enable) : **55.2 MB**
- Unity-iphone.ipa (With Bitcode And dSYM Disable) : **24.4 MB**

  So please tell me which one to upload to App Store.
  AND if (with bitcode and dSYM disable) I have to disable it in build settings ( *Enable Bitcode to NO and Debug info. format release to DWARF only* ) and compile the project again and make archive again **OR** Just while uploading archive toApp Store, I uncheck both options.

  Please help as I am doing it for the first time and it matters as there is huge differences in File sizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bigger is the better for your case.

- DSYMs files will let you have more informations if you app crashed in the future

  - not in the final .ipa of the client
- Bitcode files will let Apple recompile your app and regenerate .ipas available on the store if they improve compilation, or for example a future architecture you didn't compile for.

  - not in the final .ipa of the client

Upload it, and you will see, in Testflight section (iTUnesConnect -> Your App -> Activity -> All Builds (left panel) -> Your build -> AppStore Size link), the real size of your app for each iPhone/iPad. for example i uploaded a 150Mb size bundle, and finally, the .ipa size for iPhone 7 is only 40Mb.

Comment: Thanks For reply..this is exactly what I want to know that what happen to app sizes after uploading archive to iTunes connect. I thought I will cross 100 MB Limit. So now If I Upload 163 MB Archive then there must be no problem And user see its size as 40-45 MB Approx and then no need to download via Wifi network. Thanks!

Comment: So now App Store not take 163 MB as cellular download limits  & shows 40 MB to user ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in "iTunesConnect -> Your App -> Activity -> All Builds (left panel) -> Your build -> AppStore Size link" (the top one is downloaded by laptop i think, for iTunes stuff)

Comment: In Activity, Its. showing Compressed File Size :40.7 MB.... But In  App Store File Sizes it shows : Universal : 200 MB and for all others its 185 MB. So I want to know which file size is visible to user on App Store : 40.7 MB Or 200 Mb. And if all dSym links & Bitcode stripped off then why the file size is so huge ?