# All Build for iTunes Connect, there was an error importing this build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I upload my build to app store, after that it show error in Activity.

[image: This is the error shown]

Any one help me out.

Comment: Can you share EMAIL which iTune would have sent to you (to Account which is having this iTune Account)

Comment: they sent regarding, my app review. how they will test my app. that was long time back. now i want to upload new binary and facing this issues.

Comment: @vikash1307 whats the reason for this. I am also facing this issue.

Comment: @sateesh, actually my app version was 1.1.7 and i updated to 1.1.13. So iTunes consider that, it was lower version then previous version.
It is necessary that you upload a higher version number than previously used. For example, 1.1.71 and 1.1.8 are considered higher version numbers, but 1.1.69 and 1.1.13 are both considered lower than 1.1.7.

Comment: @vikash1307 your build versions are showing 1.3 and 1.4. And you are telling about 1.1.7 . Am i mistaken about version. How do we know the problem is it . Please let us know. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sateesh, when you create your new app version , that time you need to check ,That should be always greater than previous version. When you upload binary to App Store it will you bundle version.

Comment: @vikash1307 how do you know the error actually it is. Have you called to apple or some thing else like trail and error.

Comment: @vikash1307 our build versions are proper. So I just want to know the proper way to find the solution.

Comment: @sateesh, ya i sent a email to apple through my apple account and i got response from them.

Comment: @vikash1307 thanks a lot for your response. I will follow the same.

Comment: @sateesh and what is a solution? I have some problem.

Comment: @alexmorhun in my case it a weird issue. Google maps library has been corrupted. the apple is giving a weird message for this. I go through the apple forums and lot of stack overflow. there are various reasons for this issue. I hope its better to contact apple .

Comment: @alexmorhun  in the project and targets set enable bitcode to NO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED!**

Go to Build Settings > Search for "*bitcode*" > Turn **Enable Bitcode** to **No**

This will fix it. Also, if you are apprehensive about disabling bitcode, don't worry. Apple describes bitcode as follows:

> Bitcode is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
> you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
> linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to
> re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a
> new version of your app to the store.

You don't really need to enable it. Read more about bitcode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7).

That's it.

Your build should go through now.

Comment: I was struggling with this error for couple days and Apple didn't react on support request (so far).
I uploaded several version numbers (1.1.1, 1.1.2), but this didn't have impact - all builds finished with "there was an error importing this build"
Finally I tried this solution and during upload to AppStore switched off flag "bitcode" (in the upload dialog). Now I have my build processed without errors

Comment: Bitcode cannot be disabled for tvOS. Xcode says "target 'XXX' has bitcode disabled (ENABLE_BITCODE = NO), but it is required for the 'appletvos' platform" :(

Comment: @flopr you're right, in tvOS you probably need it. Let me try to dig in and see if I can find a solution for you that. I'll tag you if I do..

Comment: OK disabling bitcode works but this isn't really a fix. Still waiting Apple's answer on this.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed now. I have successfully uploaded a tvOS build (with bitcode) yesterday.

Comment: I am too facing the same issue, did anyone find any other solution to solve the issue, coz i can not disable the the bitcode as it is mandatory for watch os.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent the last few days battling this issue. I've finally sussed out our specific problem and thought it worthwhile sharing.  The error was the same as the original posters with iTunes Connect giving a "There was an error importing this build." error as follows:

[image]

I tried all sorts to solve this but in my travels the give away of the problem was that one of our many *.bundle files was appearing in the 'Binary and Entitlments' list during the upload/submission process:

[image]

Digging a little further when I inspected the contents of that particular *.bundle (with-in either the *.ipa or in the build folder of derived data) there was an unexpected unix executable file.  None of other *.bundle files contained a unix executable.

[image]

After some trial and error I was able to prevent the executable from being created and added to the bundle by changing the "VERSION_SYSTEM" build setting to "None" (it had inadvertently been set to "Apple Generic" in some recent xcconfig changes).

Anyway, that solved the problem for us. Hope it helps.

*An alternative (but less desirable) solution was to remove the (empty) "Compile Sources" step from the targets "Build Phases".*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your version number to a higher value. If you change only the build number it won't work. I had the same issue after my app binary had been rejected.

**Example:**

App 1.0.0 (1) -> rejected for some reason.

App 1.0.0 (2) -> you'll get the "There was an error importing this build"

App 1.0.0 (3) -> same error..

App 1.0.1 (1) -> will work!

Cheers,

Comment: This is not the correct answer. If the version number was the issue, you won't be able to upload it to itunes unless you increment it.

Comment: In fact this is the only hack, which works.