# iTunes Connect: There was an error importing this build

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm working on an iOS app that last week had a build successfully uploaded to iTunes Connect and then distributed for testing via TestFlight.

This week, I updated to Xcode 7.3 and now when I update the same project (with changes just for Swift 2.2 compatibility and some other bug fixes I did), I am able to archive and submit the build through Xcode, but then instead of processing and receiving an email that the build is ready to test, the build shows up in iTunes Connect like this, with the displayed error message. I don't receive any email or other error message about what could be wrong:

[image]

I haven't found any other solutions searching online about this issue. I've gotten in contact with Apple and the issue has been escalated but haven't heard back yet.

**Update** - Apple has escalated to engineering, awaiting response.

**Update 2** - Apple replied that this is a known issue with Xcode 7.3 and Bitcode, see answer below for solution.

Comment: What happens if you delete a previous build from itunes connect and re-upload it from an old archive that was compiled with your old x-code version?

Comment: Hitting the same issue did you resolve it? Application loader was no help.

Comment: This has hit me recently as well.  With the number of people reporting this in the apple forums and stackoverflow we can almost certainly conclude it's a problem on Apple's side.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? Seeing same issue since 2 days.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us posted on this.

Comment: This issue seems to be fixed now. I have successfully uploaded a tvOS build (with bitcode) yesterday.

Comment: I can confirm, builds are now working - I'll make a note about it being resolved in the answer. Thanks @flopr

Comment: Looks like the issue is back. Xcode 8 and I'm uploading an app that doesn't have bitcode. :-(

Comment: @DanielT. - I'd contact Apple directly (and let us know if they say what it could be - this error message is nonspecific), but do check for bit code in your settings as it can be enabled in a couple spots.

Comment: @sschale I incremented the build number and tried again and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All Build for iTunes Connect, there was an error importing this build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146731/all-build-for-itunes-connect-there-was-an-error-importing-this-build)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apple has replied that this is a known issue with `Xcode 7.3` and Bitcode. So, I disabled including Bitcode uploading with the binary and it successfully processed!:

[image]

You **do not** need to disable it for the entire project, but it works that way too (tested with both project Bitcode enabled/disabled with Bitcode upload inclusion disabled).

**Edit**: Builds as of 4/7/16 are now successfully uploading and processing with Bitcode.

Comment: I disabled bit code just as you instructed and it worked fine.  My app just got successfully uploaded and is now in a "Processing" status.  Hopefully, disabling bit code does not negatively impact my app when i go to production.

Comment: You cannot disable bitcode for AppleTV targets. Might also apply to WatchKit targets.

Comment: Very true - there have been separate threads about this for tvOS in the past on apple developer forums.

Answer (score 10):

I received this error for the first time yesterday.
I did not have bitcode turned on.
I had no other message beyond the iTunes "There was an error importing this build".

Today I **bumped up the version number and resubmitted** and it worked.

[image]

Comment: This should be the first thing to try - I'm using fastlane to deliver and hit this problem yesterday. Today I just re-ran fastlane which auto-bumped the number and it succeeded, no other changes.

Comment: I ran into this problem after I accidentally closed my Mac while the app was being uploaded to iTC. Bumping the build number and resubmitting (without closing my Mac) was successful.

Comment: I only needed to bump up the build number and it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Random problems like this happen to me sometimes and instead of uploading from the Xcode organizer what I do is use the organizer to export a build and then use Application Loader (available from the Xcode menu -> Open Developer Tool) to actually upload it. Sometimes it helps and sometimes it doesn't, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if aforementioned solution not worked for you try the following. Cause none of the listed solution worked for me.

1. Check for the Xcode Version. It should not be a BETA release.
2. If still getting issue the upload it using Application Loader. Don't use CMD + Space to launch Application Loader. It might open old or different version Application Loader. Which leads you to ambiguous bugs. Launch from the Xcode menu `Xcode -> Open developer tool -> Application Loader` solves the problem. Please make sure you do it from the version of the Xcode that you used to build your app.

Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Give it some time(an hour or two). It auto-solves.

May or may not work be a good advice, but this is what worked for me.