# What is different between run and archive, both use Release build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode

I set run build configuration to build a run.app file and export to run.ipa, then use archive to build a archive.app file and export to archive.ipa, but the size of them is difference, run.ipa is larger about 5MB than archive.ipa.

So the question is what is different between run and archive, both use Release build configuration? Why the size of them is difference?

[image]
left: archive.app right: run.app

Comment: Unzip the two ipa files and see where the size difference is.

Comment: Archive adds some Apple Store configuration as well

Comment: @rmaddy I have added the screenshot, the size of app unix executable file is difference.

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil  but why the size is difference? Archive is smaller than Run.

Comment: @MellongLau, I think this is because of bitcode, check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7

Comment: @IAmDav thanks for your reply, but I have disabled bitcode.