# Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.42.1_0' Reader: '703.0.29_0') with Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 7.3 and added Firebase SDK using cocoa pods. It adds 3.14 version of it.

Now when I am trying to archive it, it throws this error:

```
error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.42.1_0' Reader: '703.0.29_0').
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.35.0\_0' Reader: '703.0.31\_0')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875117/error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-800-0-35-0-0-reader-703-0-31-0)

Answer (score 1):

If I believe Firebase SDK when fetched thru pod gets latest and greatest of Xcode built version (8.1 or 8.2). You may like to upgrade Xcode to latest and try.
Similar query: [error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.35.0_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875117/error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-800-0-35-0-0-reader-703-0-31-0)

Comment: Hi, I have fixed this issue. It was happening because when we add firebase sdk via pod to our project, it also added GoogleUtilityForMac, I have turned off the bitcode but this repo was using bitcode. So I have turned off bitcode for this also. and Hurray It worked :) So there is no need to upgrade Xcode for now

Comment: Select Pods folder in xcode and search for bitcode keyword in Build Settings and change it to NO then archive again --> i should work fine now