# Xcode - 7.3.1 Error : Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.42.1_0' Reader: '703.0.31_0')

Tags: xcode, swift2, cocoapods, xcode7.3

I can not find out the error although several efforts have been applied. My pod file is given below.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'BB’ do
    pod 'Alamofire', '3.4.0'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3.0'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
    pod 'MFSideMenu'
    pod 'ZBarSDK', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'FMDB'
end
```

If You have any more question please ask me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '800.0.35.0\_0' Reader: '703.0.31\_0')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875117/error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-800-0-35-0-0-reader-703-0-31-0)