# Adding .a static library built on Xcode8.1 to a project, still getting Invalid bitcode version error?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, bitcode, xcode8

I am creating a .a static library with bitcode enabled on lower version of Xcode (Xcode 8.1) and adding to a project to verify it. Still getting

> Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '802.0.42.0_0' Reader: '800.0.42.1_0')

Earlier I had Xcode 8.3.3 installed as well, but I uninstalled it just to see if it was creating a problem. Seems like even after creating/compiling this library on Xcode 8.1, still it is giving error like it is built on Xcode 8.3.3. I have verified that while building the static library, the command line tool is set for Xcode 8.1

Comment: set bitcode to NO

Comment: if it Set YES, made it  NO This link will help .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875117/error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-800-0-35-0-0-reader-703-0-31-0

Comment: @V12  I actually want to build with Bitcode Enabled.

Comment: did you removed any framework from your app and install through the pod ? because this may happen when we delete any static frame work and install it through Pods.