# `Bugfender SDK` Invalid bitcode version issue

Tags: ios, swift, bugfender

I have added Bugfender SDK in my iOS app, app runs successfully in device but while archiving it gives me following error:

> could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1000.11.45.2_0' Reader: '902.0.39.2_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 9.1.0, (clang-902.0.39.2)' for architecture armv7

I'd already tried by setting **enable bitcode NO**
but didn't worked for me

Comment: Disabling Bitcode is probably what you should do for a compiled library. Did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project? Also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875117/error-invalid-bitcode-version-producer-800-0-35-0-0-reader-703-0-31-0

Comment: @gimix i have tried `Disabling Bitcode` and `cleaning and rebuilding` project but not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution, its actually weird but setting **Enable Bitcode > NO** didn't worked for me
But when i select `Pods > TARGETS > BugfenderSDK > Build Settings > Enable Bitcode > NO` everything works perfectly fine for me.

Attaching screenshot for the above step

[image]