# @2x, @3x images only working when installed from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, retina-display

When I run and install my app from Xcode, **@2x**, **@3x** images work as expected. However when I package the app into a `.ipa` file for enterprise distribution and install it, the images look blurry and I'm assuming system its only rendering the original (**@1x**) image.

How can I fix?

I'm using the asset catalog. Here is an example of an image from the asset catalog:
[image]

Comment: first of all, unzip your .ipa and check that it has/not that resources

Comment: How are you storing your images in your app (Asset Catalog? As a file?)? How are you using your images in your app - show your code. And are you sure the images are `@1x` and you are testing on an `@2x` or `@3x` device?

Comment: This won't do anything to fix whatever's going on, but to be *certain* you're seeing what you think you're seeing, temporarily edit your images - such as adding "1x" "2x" or "3x" to the image itself - so you can easily confirm which version is being displayed.

Comment: @sage444 strange, I looked at the contents of my .car file and only see 2 images per image instead of 3

Comment: @RoboticCat I'm using Asset Catalog. I have attached a screenshot

Comment: @MobileMon That's the way asset catalogs and the whole `@nx` stuff is intended to work. Before and now due to app slimming, Apple strips the sizes you don't need from the installable app. So if you download your app on a non-retina 3GS(lol) you will only get 1x images.

Comment: @OscarApeland but I was just looking at the .ipa I built myself from Xcode. Also was installing this on a retina device. So I was thinking it had something to do with bitcode so I tried toggling that on and off but no luck

Comment: Bitcode is one of the three components that makes up app slimming. Bitcode allows apple to modify and optimise the binary without requiring a re-upload. Disabling it will not affect the images in any way. This answer sums it up nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722686/1278026