# how decrease huge .ipa file size while resources are 5mb

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ipa

I'm using third-party libraries like GoogleMaps,....

[image]

But my resources like image,font and etc are less than 5mb.

How can I decrease my .ipa file size, it goes upto 89mb when archive it.

[image]

Comment: Use less than third party libraries, it's a way ^^

Comment: Does the size change if you disable bitcode?

Comment: I didn't try to disable bitcode

Comment: i did disabled bitcode and size reduced to 27mb, what will be affects of turning off? @algrid

Comment: You can see the discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722606/what-does-enable-bitcode-do-in-xcode-7 I’d say it’s ok to have it disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the archive size, it is not the final app size. Upload to iTunes Connect and check there the size of the app per device.

Comment: this is right, but I don't have DA. so I archive it and publish .ipa in archive file