# How to install Clang 9 on Mac?

Tags: macos, clang, clang++

Here's what I have on my Mac:

```
clang --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

my app needs to be compiled with clang version 9, how can I install it on my Mac?

I went to [LLVM official site](http://llvm.org/), but I don't see Clang 9 there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're talking about two different things here.  There's "LLVM X", which comes from llvm.org, and consists of clang (and lots of other things). The current release is 8.0 (just two weeks old). LLVM 9 will be out this summer.   Then there's "Apple LLVM", which is a modified version shipped by Apple as part of their developer tools. You have the current version (10.0.xxxx). Apple LLVM 9 (9.0.xxx) was the previous version. Look for an older download on Apple's site.

Comment: Got it, that's great explanation and clarification!

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 9.2 and then did `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and then my `clang --version` shows `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`, which is what I want. I guess Apple ships its clang version along with Xcode?

Comment: @FischerCoder - Apple ships (shipped?) it with Xcode and as a separate download as well, under the rubric "Command-line tools"

Comment: right, shipped*, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded `Xcode 9.2` and then did `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and then my `clang --version` shows `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`, which is what I want. 
Hope this could help others who encounter the same or similar issue.